# Azure AppService>Networking>Access Restrictions & handling 308 redirects from API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

Just wanted to see if there were any Azure App Service or APIM experts that could help me get past something that is puzzling me when it comes to **restricting access to my app service endpoint to the IP address of my Azure API Management service**. I can successfully set the APIM's ip address in an "allow" rule, in the Access Restrictions section of the networking tab, in the app service I am targeting. What happens though, is that the APIM redirects my browser to hit the app service endpoint with its own IP address, which of course I just set to be restricted only to allow access from the APIM IP address.

[image: Image of APIM route pointing to app service in backend slot]

[image: Image of access restriction rule I set on my targeted app service]

A 308 Moved Permanently http code is delivered to my browser and my browser is sent to the app service page. I am met with a 403 restricted error, because it is indeed my IP address that is accessing the app service. I am expecting to be redirected to my desired app service, and to be allowed access because it was passed from the "allowed" IP address of my APIM. Do I need to adjust this somehow with an APIM policy, or some kind of networking policy inside the targeted app service?

When I attempt to hit the app from the APIM endpoint, my redirect causes web app to restrict MY IP address

[image: Error 403 - Forbidden image]

Any thoughts at all would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIM never replies with redirect on its own, so I assume that your backend does that. By default APIM will just pass backend http response to client, no matter the status code. But you can use policies to decide what to do with response in general. For redirect specifically, there is an option `follow-redirects` on [forward-request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ForwardRequest) policy that does what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting clients to go to your app service directly, you cannot put an IP restriction on your App Service. The App Service doesn't know anything about the redirect coming from APIM (and thus that you want to allow it). Also, if you put a 308 Redirect in, the next time the client might (based on its cache) to hit the App Service directly, without going to APIM first again.

So: What you are trying here doesn't work - and doesn't make too much sense either. If you want all your clients to go through APIM, then forward the request in APIM instead of redirecting the clients.

Comment: I appreciate your response very much, can you please elaborate on that last part a bit more? I was thinking that setting the backend-service-url in the APIM API Operation (the API Management service's endpoint handler) would do what you describe, forward the request  in APIM. 
Besides setting the backend service, do I need to apply a "forward-request" policy in the "backend" portion of the Operation policies? Or, do I need to do a totally new "send-request" policy for the backend service url that I am targeted to recognize the request is coming from APIM, not the client browser IP?

Comment: @AzureGuy422 please post relevant parts from your policy definition in your post

Comment: I had no policy definition created yet actually. My thinking was that setting an endpoint as the "backend service" in an API Operation inside Azure APIM would hit that endpoint while still keeping the client on the host endpoint "xxxx.azure-apim.net/xx"